# color palette not working on certain colors in VGA

Tags: assembly, graphics, tasm, dosbox, vga

I'm trying to set the VGA(640x480x16) color palette in assembler on DOSBox but specifically colors 6, 8-F don't change. I have tried using interrupts and directly through ports both work for other colors but not for those. I'm using DOSBox 0.74-3 on default config. Here is my code

```
    setpalete MACRO index,r,g,b
            mov ax, 1010h
            mov bx, index
            mov ch, r
            mov cl, g
            mov dh, b
            int 10h
    ENDM
    Start:
        mov ax, 0A000h
        mov es, ax

        ;set video mode to 640x480 16 color ah=0 al=12h int 10h
        mov ax, 12h 
        int 10h

        setpalete 06h,030h,030h,030h

        mov dx, 03C4h ;dx = indexregister
        mov ah, 06h ;Color 
        mov al, 02h ;register select - map mask
        out dx, ax ;select the bitplanes.
        mov al, 0FFh
        mov di, 0
        mov cx,38400
        rep stosb
```

and here is setting the pallet using ports

```
setpalete MACRO index,r,g,b
    mov dx, 3c8h
    mov al, index
    out dx, al
    mov dx, 3c9h
    mov al, r
    out dx, al ; set R
    mov al, g
    out dx, al ; set G
    mov al, b
    out dx, al ; set B
ENDM
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program sets **color register 6** to some gray color. What you observe is that in the 16-color video mode 12h, palette register 6 is mapped to color register 20 (14h). So rather change color register 20 (14h). Same applies for the palette registers 8 (08h) to 15 (0Fh).

Here is the connection between the palette register (the color value) and the color register (DAC register which you should change). All numbers in hex:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6 7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F     palette register
0  1  2  3  4  5 14 7 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F     color register
```

So, for example, in order to update the color in palette register number 0Ah you should make the change in color register number 3Ah.

---

Also, your *setpalete* macro does not load the correct RGB registers. This is the correct version:

```
setpalete MACRO index,r,g,b
        mov bx, index
        mov dh, r
        mov ch, g
        mov cl, b
        mov ax, 1010h  ; BIOS.SetIndividualColorRegister
        int 10h
ENDM
```

Comment: This works! But why would anyone number the colors in such a bizarre way?

Comment: That's all to do with how the graphics cards have evolved over time going from MDA to CGA, EGA, VGA, ... Always adding more features/capabilities and always striving to stay as compatible as possible.